# The problem in crawl the every next page using beautifulsoup and webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl all the links of jobs from https://www.vietnamworks.com/tim-viec-lam/tat-ca-viec-lam by using `BeautifulSoup` and `Selenium`. 
 The problem is that I just only can crawl the links of the 1st page and don't know how to crawl the link from every next page.
This is the code I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import array as arr
import pandas as pd
#The first line import the Web Driver, and the second import Chrome Options
#-----------------------------------#

#Chrome Options
all_link = []

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument ('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument ("--igcognito")
chrome_options.add_argument ("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument ('--headless')
#-----------------------------------#

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path="C:/webdriver/chromedriver.exe")
 
 #Open url
url = "https://www.vietnamworks.com/tim-viec-lam/tat-ca-viec-lam"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
#-----------------------------------#

page_source = driver.page_source

page = page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"html.parser")


block_job_list = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center logo-area-wrapper logo-border"})
for i in block_job_list:
    link = i.find("a")
    all_link.append("https://www.vietnamworks.com/"+ link.get("href"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your problem is traversing through the pages, this code will help you do that. Insert the scraping code inside the `while` loop as mentioned.

```
from selenium import  webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import  ChromeDriverManager       # use pip install webdriver_manager if not installed

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
CDM = ChromeDriverManager()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CDM.install(),options=option)

url = 'https://www.vietnamworks.com/tim-viec-lam/tat-ca-viec-lam'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

page_num = 1
links = []
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")

while True:

    # create the soup element here so that it can get the page source of every page        

    # sample scraping of url's of the jobs posted
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('job-title '):
        links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

    # moves to next page
    try:
        print(f'On page {str(page_num)}')
        print()
        page_num+=1
        driver.find_element_by_link_text(str(page_num)).click()
        time.sleep(3)

    # checks only at the end of the page
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('End of pages')
        break

driver.quit()
```

**EDIT:**

1. Simplified and modified the pagination method
2. If you are using `BeautifulSoup` then you have to insert the `page_source` and `soup` variables inside the `while` loop because after every iteration, the source page code changes. In your code you had extracted only the first page's source code and hence you got repetitive outputs **which is equal to the number of pages.**
3. By using `ChromeDriverManager` in the package `webdriver-manager`, the need to mention the location/executable path is not needed. You can just copy paste this code and run it in any machine that has **Chrome** installed in it. If you have to installed use `pip install webdriver_manager` in cmd before running the code.

**Warning:** AVOID DISPLAYING your actual *username* and *password* of any of your accounts like you have in your `GitHub` code.

Comment: Sincerely thanks but may I ask that why while I run the code, the terminal responsed that "a[2].click()
NameError: name 'a' is not defined"

Comment: Sorry I had missed out a line in code, I have now removed the excess print statements added the needed line. check it out.

Comment: hi Ananth, I found an error that the crawled link was repeated when using your code. it means the information of the 1st pages repeated the same times as the number of pages. Hope you can check it out

Comment: oh well I check the web driver without the `chrome_options.add_argument ('--headless')` and the page was going next but I can understand while I put my scraping code into its place, the results return only the link of the first page and repeated for times equal to the number of page @@ here is my code : https://github.com/gialuong2801/abc/blob/main/test1.py
can you check it :(

Comment: @ Loung, I have edited and added some suggestions, check it out and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: oh thanks, it worked very well. By the way, using your old code, if I want to decide which page the program will stop to crawl, what should I do

Comment: Change the `while` loop condition to stop at a particular page. If you want to stop at page number 5 then use `while page_num <= 5:` instead of `while True:`. This will stop the crawling at page number 5. Note that this is if you want to stop after scraping some number of pages, it does not apply to scrapping only a particular page - for example if you want to scrape only page number 5 then use an if condition inside the while loop.